# Reinstall Ubuntu via USB?

Tags: system-installation, usb

*New to Linux.*

I put Ubuntu on my USB stick; installed Ubuntu while removing Windows 10.
Currently on single-boot Ubuntu, but it's crashing very often not long after startup, requiring full reboot each time.
I'm not sure what's causing the constant crashing. I think it may be that I configured the bootable USB wrong. So I wiped by USB and configured it again with UNetbootin.
So I want to reinstall Ubuntu, but I'm stuck as to how. When I configure my BIOS to boot my from USB, it just skips the USB and goes to the next in queue (e.g. my current Ubuntu OS).

How do I start a fresh installation of Ubuntu on my computer? (No need to worry about backing up files, the few that I need are on an external harddrive.)

Comment: Instead of waiting to boot to USB, what happens if you choose the USB from boot menu? Depending on make & model, most boot menus can be reached by hitting F12 / Del / Enter at boot.

Comment: I've always had issues making a bootable usb from Ubuntu. Try making one on a friend's computer.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer is: download a Ubuntu .iso and burn it to DVD, then boot the DVD and install from there. Much more reliable than USB flash drive.

On a different note... if you're at all experienced with the terminal application, and you want to trying diagnosing the reason for your current crash situation, open `terminal` from the dash, and you can `cd /var/log` *(to change directories)* and `more syslog` or `more syslog.1` *(to display the error logs)*, looking for error information about the crash.

Cheers, Al

Answer (score 0):

If you are using unetbootig, repeat the process again, and configure your USB. I dont know why this happens, but it has happened to me two times. The first time you make the booteable USB, it won't work, but, if you create the startup disk again, it works. It is weird but works, at least for me.

Also, check the BIOS boot preference, order and devices.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

1- Download the [Ubuntu iso](http://www.ubuntu.com/download).

2- Dowload [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/)

3- Start Rufus, plug your usb, select your usb in rufus and select your Ubuntu iso file in Rufus and start.

4- After finished, you have a Bootable USB with Ubuntu

5- a- In your bios setup, boot menu, select 1st option as USB

b- Or with fast boot while starting, mostly f11 key (find your pc key) and choose your flash disk.

6- You can make a clear partition again during Ubuntu install for a fresh OS.

7- After finished installation

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

That's all... Good Luck